# Unity usernames not showing

Tags: c#, multiplayer, unity-networking

I have a little multiplayer game with Unity. As the Host(car named NiciBozz) it looks like this:
[image: Host view]

This is fine, but as a client(here named NiciBot) it looks like this:
[image: Client View]

The Code related to the usernames:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.Networking;
using UnityEngine.UI;
[NetworkSettings(channel = 1, sendInterval = 0.2f)]

public class PlayerControll : NetworkBehaviour
{
    public Text Name;

    [SyncVar]
    public string playerName;

    private void Start()
    {
        if (isLocalPlayer)
        {
            CmdChangeName(PlayerPrefs.GetString("Name"));
        }
    }

    [Command(channel =1)]
    private void CmdChangeName(string name)
    {
        if (!isLocalPlayer)
        {
            Name.text = name;
            playerName = name;
            SetDirtyBit(1);
            return;
        }
        Name.text = name;
        playerName = name;
        SetDirtyBit(1);
    }
}
```

What should I do to sync the usernames properly?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you only try to set the name if `isLocalPlayer` is true, but in `CmdChangeName` you have an `if` that checks the value of `isLocalPlayer` (which will always be `true` based on your snippet).

Do you call `CmdChangeName` elsewhere?

Comment: No. But it won't change anything since the content is the same.

Comment: Then how does that "ASDFASDF" show up above the cars?

Comment: its the default text of the ui.text element

Comment: Could you try removing `if (isLocalPlayer)` and leave the rest in your `Start()` method?

Comment: So only leave `CmdChangeName(PlayerPrefs.GetString("Name"));` in there. What happens?

Comment: Nothing happens

Comment: So you have the same results, all ok for host but default names for client?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136533/discussion-between-nicibozz-and-mihai-ovidiu-drgoi).

Answer (score 0):

Make use of [syncVar](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Networking.SyncVarAttribute.html) with command Something like this:

```
   [SyncVar]//server to client. sync this variable name across all clients

   public string localPlayerName = "Player";

   void OnGUI()
    {
        if (isLocalPlayer)
        {
            localPlayerName = GUI.TextField(new Rect(0, 0, 100, 20), localPlayerName);

            if (GUI.Button(new Rect(110, 0, 100, 20), "Name"))
            {
                CmdUpdateLocalPlayerName(localPlayerName);

            }
        }
    }

    [Command]//client to server
    void CmdUpdateLocalPlayerName(string userName)
    {
        localPlayerName = userName;
    }
```